# Highcharts Bar Chart Tooltips multiple content panes brake in FireFox

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, tooltip, contentpane

I created an application that uses a content panes. Each page loads in the master content pane and others open in a tab format, so the user can flip back and forth and does not have to reload the page.

I added multiple Highchart graphs to each page. Everything looks great! When the user clicks each page the charts load fine. As you click though each tab/page, the bar charts look fine; however, the tooltip only works on the first bar graph within FireFox. Surprisingly, IE it works and other charts on the page display tooltips fine.

Each Chart has an unique ID. I noticed that other charts (Pie) used in the same way work fine and display the tooltip as expected. The issue seems to with Bar Charts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to render charts in hidden divs / tabs ? Have you sorted data by x ascending?

Comment: Yes, I tried both hidden and visible divs. Bar charts do not show tooltips after the second tab is clicked. The chart renders fine. Not sure what you mean by sorted data by x ascending?

Comment: Highcharts cannot be rendered in hidden object.
If you use datetime xAxis type, then you need have sorted data.